# javascript not showing on heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have launched a rails app on Heroku and as always works as expected. The issue now is that I have a back to top button button and and image preview that have stopped working on heroku for some reason (was working for a good while then just stopped). They still work locally as expected. What I have tried so far is the following:

1. Changed "config.assets.compile = false" to "config.assets.compile = true"
2. bundle exec rake assets:precompile
3. purging cache
4. added new BTP buttons

Any help would be very much appreciated as I am stumped and cannot find any helpful resource as of yet. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any errors? Can you see the JS being loaded in the browser devtools/network tab?

Comment: yes and no errors but I'm also thinking now that would it be possible that its not getting the display in css? these are hidden before they needed and the js calls the classes to make visible again.

Comment: Just checked again and is js not working!